# Android Design Lib CollapsingToolbarLayout stops interact when horizontal RecyclerView is touched

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an activity with CollapsingToolbarLayout for parallax effect(From Android Design Library) and FrameLayout where i set Fragment.

Fragments layout contains NestedScrollView.

Everything is working well except one moment. In NestedScrollView I have a horizontal RecyclerView with StaggerGridLayoutManager and when i scroll vertically from that recyclerview - parallax not starting. When i scroll from any other place of screen it works.

Seems it's problem with layout_behavior tag or loosing focus of NestedScrollView.

Does any one faced this problem  ? Some ideas ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fuh! Got a solution! Disabling nested scroll on RecyclerView solved the problem.

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Hi even I'm using StaggerGridLayoutManager in nestedscrollview. I have a view above the recyclerview and if I scroll it get fixed at the top not scrolling till the end. Pls help

Comment: dude you are perfect ;)